# Flash ActionScript missing comma (,)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I validated registration form in ActionScript, after validation I want to show following message.

```
var poptxt = "Dear Seeker,\n Please specify your Name, Gender and Birth date";
```

In this message out put comma (`,`) is missing.

How can I display comma in my validation message?

Comment: Are you using an embedded font in the text field? If so check that you have punctuation embedded along with characters.

Comment: Hi Paul, i am new in flash could you please explain me what exactly i want to do. i am basically developer in .Net, we don't have any professional flash developer so that this project is assign to me. please help me.

Comment: If you are using the Flash IDE and have a textfield on the stage, make sure you have the 'properties' window open, click the textfield and look in the properties window for 'Embed'. Click that and see what it says. You have the option to embed full character sets or individual characters. You may need to embed 'punctuation'

Comment: Hi Paul, your solution is working fine, your great thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has a great tutorial on embedding fonts, with a visual:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html

@paul why dont you answer with an answer?  I dont want to steal anything, so hopefully paul with just answer, and you can click his.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an embedded font check what characters you have embedded.

Using the Flash IDE with a textfield on the stage, make sure you have the 'properties' window open, click the textfield and look in the properties window for 'Embed'. Click that and see what it says. You have the option to embed full character sets or individual characters. You may need to embed 'punctuation'.